# SQL: How to CONCAT value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I return the values of MainEmail in the query below, delimited by commas and still count MDCselect?

```
declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='hospital 1'
    select distinct mainhospital , f.Item, count(*) Count
    from SurveyPicList s
    cross apply splitstrings(s.MDCselect,':') as f
    WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
    GROUP BY MainHospital, f.Item
    ORDER BY Count DESC
```

To be clear the above returns this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8auk.jpg

So there were 3 separate entries/people that selected "02-Eye". I want to list out their emails(MainEmail) comma delimited. Please let me know if I am unclear.

Comment: why the downvote? let me know what I can improve

Comment: You did not state which database system. This question will need a database specific answer. (I did not down vote.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from your use of `CROSS APPLY` that you are using SQL Server, and that it is at least version 2005, you can use XML to do the concatenation as follows:

```
declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='hospital 1';

select mainhospital , f.Item, count(*) Count
       ,Stuff(
           (select distinct ', ' + m.MainEmail
              from SurveyPicList m
             where m.MainHospital = @MainHospital
               and ':' + m.MDCselect + ':' like '%:' + f.Item + ':%'
            FOR XML PATH ('')),
           1, 2, '') as Emails
    from SurveyPicList s
    cross apply splitstrings(s.MDCselect,':') as f
    WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
    GROUP BY MainHospital, f.Item
    ORDER BY Count DESC
```

From the name I am assuming that `splitstrings` splits its first argument into items separated by its second argument. Hence I used `like` to check for `f.Item` in `m.MDCselect` in the `WHERE` condition of the subselect. Actually, what this `WHERE` condition is doing is collecting all the rows from another instance of the same table that match one record in the final grouped output.

Comment: inserting the block 'stuff throws a hand full of errors. "The Stuff argument requires 4 arguments", couldn't bind f.Item and s.PicListId/PK

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the parentheses around the `''` of the `FOR XML PATH`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 20
Must declare the scalar variable "@MainHospital".

Comment: Sorry, I had just copied the SQL statement without the variable declaration, now I added that as well.

Comment: Column 'SurveyPicList.PicListId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: fantastic stuff FrankPI, works like a charm. thanks!